# How to get Visual object of my own app's window or a particular UIElement like a grid?

Tags: uwp, screen-recording

I am trying to capture my own app's window, to record a video of it. From my understanding, UWP provides 2 ways to create the [GraphicsCaptureItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.capture.graphicscaptureitem?view=winrt-19041), the first is [GraphicsCapturePicker()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.capture.graphicscapturepicker?view=winrt-19041) to select the app window of the user's choice. The second is to create it from Visual using GraphicsCaptureItem.CreateFromVisual(). like this.

```
// Get our capture item
var picker = new GraphicsCapturePicker();
// var item = await picker.PickSingleItemAsync(); //1st method
// GraphicsCaptureItem item = GraphicsCaptureItem.CreateFromVisual((Visual) MainGrid); //2nd
```

The first method works without any issue. But I want to get the GraphicsCaptureItem of my own app through code, i.e, using the 2nd method. But I am clueless about how to convert my window or MyGrid UIElement to visual to create the GraphicsCaptureItem, which is required to record the video.

Comment: [ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.hosting.elementcompositionpreview.getelementvisual?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_Xaml_Hosting_ElementCompositionPreview_GetElementVisual_Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_)?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but the size of the result GraphicsCaptureItem is 0.

Comment: If you just want to capture your app's windows and record a video, what about using [AppRecordingManager Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.apprecording.apprecordingmanager?view=winrt-19041)?

Comment: Yes, you are right, now that is the class I have implemented, it works as expected. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [AppRecordingManager Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.apprecording.apprecordingmanager?view=winrt-19041) instead if you just want to caputure your app's window and record a video